# Does skeletal muscle injury cause hypertrophy or atrophy?

Tags: muscle, injury, pathophysiology, muscular-atrophy

In the following diagram from the *Love and Bailey* textbook I see that injury causes a decrease in hypertrophy due to a decrease in the expression of IGF-1. Here *Love and Bailey* consider a skeletal muscle model.

[image: From Love and Bailey]

But in *Robbins and Cotran* (diagram attached), mechanical stretch and growth factors like IGF-1 cause an increase in contractile protein synthesis. Here *Robbins and Cotran* consider a heart muscle as model.

[image: From Robbins and Cotran]

So the question is whether injury causes hypertrophy or atrophy? I feel that if injury is beyond repair then atrophy should occur, but is this what *Love and Bailey* wanted to say or is it different? Does it depend on whether the muscle is skeletal muscle or cardiac muscle?

Comment: it would most likely depend on the muscle model. cardiac muscles will still contract even in the presence of injury due to its automaticity while skeletal muscles can reduce signs of inflammation like pain by simply immobilizing that muscle. immobilizing that muscle will produce the effect of "atrophy of disuse"

Comment: This should be migrated to biology [physiology]

Comment: @GrahamChiu I would have done so had you flagged it but I didn't see this until now. It's too old to migrate now.

Comment: @CareyGregory I only saw it last month!

Comment: @GrahamChiu Oh, I wasn't blaming you. I think it would have been too old to migrate even when you first saw it. What I meant was it's better to flag when you see an issue than to comment because the mods get notified when you flag, but we don't get notified when you comment.

Comment: If the OP wants, they can still copy/paste this question to Biology and delete this one.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is hypertrophy, but if the injury is disabling, then it will lead to muscle atrophy due to disuse. Note that body builders lift weight until causing minor injury.

https://www.unm.edu/~lkravitz/Article%20folder/musclesgrowLK.html